# location of a dragged and dropped marker using leaflet

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet

I am using the leaflet API with OSM. I need to implement a functionality where on dragging the marker and dropping it on user preferred location, I need to get its latitude and longitude and save its location to database.

For now on double clicking the marker I am able to drag the marker. This line helped me:

```
draggable:true
```

Now when I release the marker I want to find the latitude and longitude of the location or invoking a function on dragging the marker, returning the `lat,lng` values.

Comment: Downvote: bad formatting, no respect for [“no please in questions” guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts#answer-3021), but most of all most [basic research](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#draggable) not done.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575722/leaflet-js-set-marker-on-click-update-postion-on-drag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any [draggable object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#draggable) will fire `dragstart`, `dragend` and other drag-related events.

Simply [listen](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events) to the `dragend` events of the [marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker) you marked as draggable, and subscribe a handler that gets the `latlng` value from the sent [event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#location-event):

```
marker.on('dragend', function(event) {
    var marker = event.target;  // you could also simply access the marker through the closure
    var result = marker.getLatLng();  // but using the passed event is cleaner
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: hi Matti, For some reason its giving me result as undefined...

Comment: @DomincJune I had been too quick and had forgot to navigate the `.target` property of `event`. This should be fixed now.

Comment: As a newbie, this post has been very useful along with [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/leaflet-js/SDtNM9QFBq4) on Leaflet Mailing List.